# Should there always be a '/system/default.prop' in android 10?

Tags: lenovo

I can't remember if there was a /system/default.prop file or wether its missing. Should there always be one, because I only have 'build.prop in system folder?

Comment: default.prop (or prop.default) is for initramfs so it should be (or symlink) whereever init is `/` in boot or system_root

Comment: I found prop.default in /system/etc folder (same folder contains init folder) and I can say the contents look like I remember. Should I copy this to /system folder or just apply the mod to this one?

Comment: As it symlinked as suggested you can change either and effects are the same. although when it comes to permissions I changed the original file (/system/etc folder)